# Should we repeat the verb after "rather than"?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

> Super AMOLED Plus uses a traditional RGB RGB (3 subpixels) arrangement typically used in LCD displays rather than the PenTile RGBG pixel matrix (2 subpixels) used in Super AMOLED.

or

> Super AMOLED Plus uses a traditional RGB RGB (3 subpixels) arrangement typically used in LCD displays rather than uses the PenTile RGBG pixel matrix (2 subpixels) used in Super AMOLED.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second option is incorrect. The continuous form of a verb should be used after "rather than" in the present tense, so it would be "rather than using".

With that change, both options are fine.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the 2nd is clearer don't u think?

Comment: @Kiti no, I find them both equally clear.

Comment: really, the non native English speaker like me can be confused if reading the 1st one.

Comment: If you find the second less confusing, why is that the one you got wrong? Even if that was just a typo, it's no reason to suppose that a different non-native speaker wouldn't find the first clearer because they are tripped by different things. As a native speaker I also find them equally clear. (I find the suggestion in Edwin's answer clearer still, though it doesn't explain as clearly as this answer that both repeating and not repeating the verb is allowed).

Answer (score 2):

The second version is arguably ungrammatical, but is an attempt to correct a fault that the first version has.

> A uses B typically used in Cs rather than the D used in E.

'typically used in Cs rather than the D used in E' could validly be taken as cohesive.

ie is the base construction

> Super AMOLED Plus uses {a traditional RGB RGB (3 subpixels) arrangement
>   typically used in LCD displays} rather than {the D used in E}

OR

> Super AMOLED Plus uses a traditional RGB (3 subpixels) arrangement, which is
>   typically {used in LCD displays} rather than {[in] the D used in E}

The choice may be obvious to people used to this technical register, but I'd find

> Rather than using the PenTile RGBG pixel matrix (2 subpixels) which is
>   used in Super AMOLED, **Super AMOLED Plus** uses a traditional RGB RGB
>   (3 subpixels) arrangement typically used in LCD displays.

much clearer.

Comment: Separating out the "typically used in Cs", with parentheses or something, could work too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very new here and I can't really explain why, but the first one is correct. There is no need to repeat the verb when using "rather than" in this context.

If someone with better credentials tells you differently, *then you may be better off taking their advice rather than mine.*

Comment: I suspect the reason you favour the first is not whether the verb is repeated, but that in the example given the verb is repeated incorrectly, as per Matt's answer.